# Making a UITextView not editable by the user

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I made this UITextView and everything is perfect except the fact that when the user taps it, the keyboard opens up. How can I disable that "editing(?)" option?
Here's the code:

```
- (void)loadAboutStable {
UITextView *aboutStable = [[UITextView alloc] init];
[aboutStable setText:@"Please check Your network connection"];
[self addSubview:aboutStable];}
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

`[aboutStable setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]` should do it

and if you still need scrolling:

```
aboutStable.editable = NO;
```

Comment: This will also prevent scrolling, which you may still want to allow.  the solution by @Jacob prevents editing but allows scrolling.

Comment: This does not allow scrolling.[textview setEditable:NO]; worked for me

Answer (score 20):

```
aboutStable.editable = NO;
```

should work

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with XIB too by UnCheck of the editable checkbox as given in below screen :
[image]

and also do it by code :

```
textViewObject.editable = false
```

Answer (score 4):

```
yourTextView.editable = NO;
```

It will make your text View not editable. It can be called from anywhere if you have made the property of you text view in .h file like this

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextView *youTextView;
```

Answer (score 4):

Select the **UITextView** in the **storyboard**

Choose the **Property Inspector** and under the **Behavior** section uncheck "**Editable**"

----Xcode version 5.0

Answer (score 1):

SWIFT 2.0 & XCODE 7.0 example for solution provided by @James Webster

1. In Main.storyboard (default), select your TextView
2. Go to the Attribute Inspector of the TextView
3. Uncheck "User Interaction Enabled"

[image: IDE example]

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4 version:

```
aboutStable.isEditable = false
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 2.0 it has to be false not NO.

```
theClues.selectable = false
```

I had a problem with making my clues appear in white letters unless I checked the selectable button on the storyboard for the textview.  However, leaving "Selectable" checked and adding the line above works.

Answer (score 0):

to really destroy any interactivity ;)

```
descriptionText.isSelectable = false;
descriptionText.isEditable = false;
```